# error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype onCreateView

Tags: javascript, android

I have this error : method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

My code :

public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    final List<Map<String, Object>> contacts = retrieveContacts(getActivity().getContentResolver());

    if (contacts != null)
    {
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), contacts, R.layout.activity_main, new String[] { "name", "photo" }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.photo });
        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation)
            {
                if ((view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap))
                {
                    final ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
                    final Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data;
                    image.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    return rootView;
}

private Bitmap getPhoto(ContentResolver contentResolver, long contactId)
{
    Bitmap photo = null;
    final Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    final Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(photoUri, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DATA15 }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null)
    {
        Log.e("getPhoto", "Cannot retrieve the photo of the contact with id '" + contactId + "'");
        return null;
    }

    if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true)
    {
        final byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);

        if (data != null)
        {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        }
    }

    if (cursor.isClosed() == false)
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return photo;
}
private List<Map<String, Object>> retrieveContacts(ContentResolver contentResolver)
{
    final List<Map<String, Object>> contacts = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER }, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null)
    {
        Log.e("retrieveContacts", "Cannot retrieve the contacts");
        return null;
    }

    if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true)
    {
        do
        {
            final long id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID)));
            final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            final int hasPhoneNumber = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0)
            {
                final Bitmap photo = getPhoto(contentResolver, id);

                final Map<String, Object> contact = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                contact.put("name", name);
                contact.put("photo", photo);

                contacts.add(contact);
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext() == true);
    }

    if (cursor.isClosed() == false)
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

}

Logcat :

06-06 12:04:42.579 3924-3924/net.lelandaislaposte.steven.contact E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: net.lelandaislaposte.steven.contact, PID: 3924
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.lelandaislaposte.steven.contact/net.lelandaislaposte.steven.contact.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.lelandaislaposte.steven.contact.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.lelandaislaposte.steven.contact.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I do not know where that comes from.

It should return the photo and the name of the contacts stored in the hone

Answer (score 0):

Make the `onCreate` method public, as the super method is public, and you cannot override it with a weaker access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The onCreateView() is a method of Fragment class

In your activity your are extending AppCompatActivity i.e creating a subclass of AppCompatActivity
There is no method onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) in AppCompatActivity class

So you are not ovveriding the merhod from superclass in your case AppComptrActivity

That is why you get the error saying method not overriding its supertype

Comment: Thank's, but more new error :  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.lelandaislaposte.steven.contact.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: @StevenLnds can you tell which line you got this error

Comment: @StevenLnds the logcat tells where the classcastexception occured ,it would be easy if you tell where the exception occured

Comment: I have make my logcat in answer

Answer (score 0):

**You can cverride below methods in your Activity class:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```